# How can capture a date from UIDatePicker to an outside variable

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, swift5

Im just trying to extract a date to a variable to be used somewhere else and to have that variable change everytime the value of the Picker changes.

```
 @IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker)  {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
       var DateString = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

        return
    }
```

Im sure its simple but Im a newbie. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it inside the vc

```
var currentDate = ""

@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker)  {
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
     currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)!
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the variable currentDate its not updating.

Comment: Every time I change the date in the interface, I can see in the console that the date is being printed nicely, so its being called, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

make an extension on Date

```
 extension Date {
            func convertDateToString(format : String) -> String {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
               return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
        }
    }
```

in your VC

```
let dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
var currentDate = Date().convertDateToString(format: dateFormat) // to get current date

@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker)  {
    currentDate = sender.date.convertDateToString(format: dateFormat)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a property observer. It's called whenever the value changes.

```
var selectedDate : Date = Date() {
    didSet {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        dateDisplay.text = dateFormatter.string(from: selectedDate)
    }
}

@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    selectedDate = sender.date
}
```